# Dropdownlist issue in grid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I have problem, I have dropdownlist in mvc telerik grid every thing is ok only problem is i added space in dropdownlist but space is showing bottom of dropdownlist i want it space on top in dropdownlist my code is

controller code:

```
private void Grid_PopulateAssignedClientCombo()
        {


            IEnumerable<AssignedClient> ass= assetManagementService.GetAssignedClients();
            IList<AssignedClient> l =new List<AssignedClient>();
            AssignedClient a = new AssignedClient();
            l = ass.ToList();
            a.ID = 0;
            a.RefAssignedClient_DESC=string.Empty;
            l.Add(a);
            ViewData["assignedClients"] = l.Select(e => new AssignedClient{ ID = e.ID, RefAssignedClient_DESC= e.RefAssignedClient_DESC});


}    
Editor template


<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
                  .Name("AssignedClient")
                  .BindTo(new SelectList((IList)ViewData["assignedClients"],"RefAssignedClient_DESC", "RefAssignedClient_DESC"))
%>
```

Can any body tell me how i can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
l.Add(a);
```

to

```
l.Insert(0, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add an order by ID . like

```
l.orderby(p=>p.ID);
```